# Missing OCI support when building GDAL

Tags: oracle, gdal

So I am building a DOTNET application that runs on Debian, and makes use of ogr2ogr to copy data from an oracle database towards an Postgres database.

The problem is that I cannot get GDAL to recognize the OCI driver.

[image: OCI support]

These are the installation commands that I have collected for now:

```
#Install dependencies used by GDAL and ora2pg
apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
        libc-bin unzip curl ca-certificates rpm libaio1 \
        #Package manager for installing Oracle
        alien \
        # Install postgresql
        postgresql-client \
        # Used for the POSTGRES_HOME variable
        libpq-dev \
        #Package manager used for installation of perl database drivers
        cpanminus \
        # Proj build
        sqlite libsqlite3-dev pkg-config g++ make

#Install Oracle
curl -o oracle-instantclient-basic.x86_64.rpm https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/199000/oracle-instantclient19.9-basic-19.9.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
curl -o oracle-instantclient-devel.x86_64.rpm https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/199000/oracle-instantclient19.9-devel-19.9.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
curl -o oracle-instantclient-sqlplus.x86_64.rpm https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/199000/oracle-instantclient19.9-sqlplus-19.9.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm

alien -i oracle-instantclient-basic.x86_64.rpm && alien -i oracle-instantclient-devel.x86_64.rpm && alien -i oracle-instantclient-sqlplus.x86_64.rpm

EXPORT ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/19.9/client64
EXPORT TNS_ADMIN=/usr/lib/oracle/19.9/client64/network/admin
EXPORT LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/19.9/client64/lib
EXPORT PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/oracle/19.9/client64/bin

#Install Postgres en Oracle drivers for perl, ora2pg  
cpanm DBD::Oracle
cpanm DBD::Pg

#Setup
wget https://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-6.3.2.tar.gz
tar -zxf proj-6.3.2.tar.gz -C /opt/
/opt/proj-6.3.2/configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static --enable-lto
make -C /opt/proj-6.3.2/
make install -C /opt/proj-6.3.2/

RUN wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/3.2.2/gdal-3.2.2.tar.gz
/opt/gdal-3.2.2/configure
make -C /opt/proj-6.3.2/
make install -C /opt/proj-6.3.2/
```

Is there anyone who can tell me what I am missing, because I cannot find any answers on the internet...

Comment: It would be better to provide all logs (configure&&make&&make install). Btw, wouldn't it be easier to use their docker image?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I will add the logs, and yes it would be easier. But I also need all the microsoft .net core stuff because I need to run the commands from a program. So that is why I take that as base image

Comment: you can build own image from different images: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov aah I didn't know that, I will check it out if it works this way, but then I need to find an image from GDAL that is on debian and has oracle included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot off testing, my colleague found the problem.
Apparently the scripts search for a folder in `$ORACLE_HOME/sdk`.
Now by installing it, like above, it doesn't install the sdk folder on the correct location.
So we solved it by adding an extra step extracting the SDK zip package on the correct location.

This is the result:
[image: Result]

[Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/kevingoos/a91b617effe7f02b55d5332e4a844290)

Comment: Could you please share the resulting Dockerfile or install command sequence? I've been stuck on the same thing for ages since the official GDAL images do not support Oracle and I did not have any succes building it on my own.

Comment: @Web_GIS No problem, you can find the secret sauce we used here: https://gist.github.com/kevingoos/a91b617effe7f02b55d5332e4a844290

Answer (score 1):

Above solution did not work for me. I needed a GDAl container with OCI. Based on some other info I found I build an image that works.

https://github.com/botenvouwer/gdal-oci

Currently you have to clone and build the image yourself. You should (but don't have to) pass the version to your docker build as ARG `GDAL_VERSION`.